# Set Associative Cache Exercises

Tags: cpu-cache

I am trying to solve an exercise on set-associative cache , i struggled with it for a while but i think that i figured out the answer , would be helpful if someone could check if my solution is correct

Here is the question:

*Considering a main memory with 1024 addresses , divided in blocks of 8 words each, and a set associative cache with 4 sets and 8 ways:*

**a) How many words can the cache memory contain?**

**b) in which cache position the word with address 75(octal) could be memorized?**

- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- other

**c) if a cache miss occurs , how many words in cache memory will be modified?**

a) We have a maain memory with 1024 locations, each location has 8 words
   1024 * 8 = 8192 words in main memory (2^13).

Then we have a set associative cache with 4 sets , 8 ways each,
 4*8 = 32 , so the cache has 32 blocks . each block  contains 8 words,
32 * 8 = 256.

So the cache can contain **256 words** (2^8)

b)

We know that in set associative cache , the main memory address is divided into

tag|set|offset

n = number of bits of the main memory address
m = number of bits of the cache memory address
b = size (expressed in words) of the block

n = 13
m = 8
b = 8

offset = log2 b = 3
set = log2 (number of sets) , 4 sets , so log2 4 = 2
tag = n - offset - set (13 - 3 - 2) = 8

so the address is divided in :
8 bits|2 bits|3 bits
tag    set    offset

The address of the word is 75(octal) , convrted in binary is 111101
it is a 6 bits address , the main memory generates 13 bits addresses,
so we rewrite it as 0000000111101 , we divide the address in:

00000001|11|101

From here we can se that the word could be memorized in any of the locations of the set 3 (11)

We have a cache with 4 sets and 8 ways each set:

[image: 4 sets 8 ways set associative cache]

So we have 32 blocks in cache , assuming we start from block 0,
we can see that the blocks in set 3 (ii) are

24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31

The question is asking in which locations the word with address 75(octal) **could** be stored, so it could be stored in one of the blocks from 24 to 31
so the answer to the question b should be: **other**

I haven't still figured out point c , but would be helpful to know if my reasoning is correct , or , where i am wrong.

Comment: I think the question is bit confusing. Can you post the actual question, please.

Comment: Ok , i will edit the post , leaving only the actual question

Comment: Sorry, its fine to have your attempts as part of the question. I got confused by "main memory with 1024 addresses , divided in blocks of 8 words each".

Comment: that part confuses me too , but the question is stated in that way , i will try to explain it in the post , the way i interpreted it , so you can tell me if it is reasonable.